# Black screen after Nvidia install

Tags: black-screen, nvidia-driver

I installed the Nvidia 340 package from the store, then all i get is a black screen and thats it. is there a way to fix it? or to intall nvidia and make it work, my card is a Nvidia gtx 750 ti

Comment: Elementary OS 6 Odin

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ any F-key from <kbd>F1</kbd> up to <kbd>F6</kbd>. This will get you to a TTY where you can log in and remove the packages in question. For example, you can try:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-340
```